# I can't return to Windows and am panicking!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

TLDR; Ubuntu is on a flashdrive. I needed to switch boot styles from UEFI to Legacy in order to launch Ubuntu. Now that I've done that I can no longer access Windows. I also cannot seem to open up BIOS (I've tried many keys and many times). I am still in Try mode on Ubuntu.

I wanted to try out Ubuntu today and so followed the installation guide on the Ubuntu website. Unfortunately, I was unable to access the BIOS menu, probably because of a fast start up or something like that. I found some advice online which told me how to restart my computer from the Settings. From there I could access the BIOS. I then switched the start up mode from UEFI to Legacy and Ubuntu started up successfully from my USB! I enjoyed playing around on it a bit in the try mode and decided I'd install it. When I got to the second prompt of the installation process though, it told me that there was no other operating system found. I decided not to install it and to restart to see what was the matter. To my surprise, without the USB plugged in, my Acer laptop told me there was no OS found. When I try to access the BIOS during start up, it either perpetually flashes screens of various shades of black before eventually telling me there is no OS, or if I try with the USB plugged in, it eventually brings me to some Ubuntu page that sort of looks like BIOS but is more like an Ubuntu help centre or something. How do I go about fixing this? Am I never going to get my data/Windows back?

Comment: Have you tried to revert boot style from Legacy to UEFI ?

Comment: If you boot with the live Ubuntu USB, you should be able to see your partitions using gparted and also browse your filesystem to see that all your windows files are still there. That will reduce the panic enough until you can enter and put the BIOS back to the way it was. Maybe try default BIOS settings.

Comment: @SorenA The problem is more that I don't know how to revert it if I am unable to access BIOS. Is there a sort of force BIOS start up you can do from Ubuntu (like with how I did originally with Windows via a troubleshoot restart)

Comment: @Katu How would I go about browsing my filesystem? From Ubuntu it looks like there is nothing in, say the documents, that I had on Windows

Comment: @lehtia open the file manager and on the left you will see 'Home', 'Documents'... followed by a list of your hard drive partitions. Click on them to mount them and browse your files. Click the Ubuntu logo and type 'gparted' to check the status of your partitions... but do not change them!

Comment: @Katu Thank you so much!! That really does relieve a lot of the stress I was feeling before! Maybe I will just go ahead with the installation then for now and sort out the Windows thing another time. Do you know what sort of Installation option I should choose? The tutorial I was following displayed an option to install alongside Windows but since the computer doesn't seem to recognize it, the option isn't there...

Comment: @lehtia now that you can see your windows documents, you must make a backup (to an external drive) before you touch anything else. I would not recommend to install Ubuntu at this point. Check your laptop model and the key to enter the BIOS, fix the BIOS, go back to your original setup with just Windows and start over again following the installation tutorials.